# Orange3 how to reapply preprocessing to new data

Tags: orange

Is there any way to reapply a preprocessment done in a training dataset to a new dataset of experimental data for submission of the transformed data to the already trained classifier?

Comment: Can't you pass the new eperimental data [through the same preprocessor](http://docs.orange.biolab.si/3/data-mining-library/reference/preprocess.html#discretization)?

Comment: Aparently not, as from what i understood from the code, the preprocessors dont have state, a call over them executes the method on the new data again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The preprocessor modifies the `domain` on the training data set. If you want to apply the same transformations on the testing (experimental) data, you apparently have to cast it into the same domain, as the Orange's built-in predictors seem to do:

```
train = preprocess(train)
test = Table(train.domain, test)
```

Comment: I will try this today.